# If condition for empty date field

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

do you know how to identify an empty date field.

When I'm doing if not empty I'm still receiving default date value if it's empty. How to get rid of it?

```
%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@RegistrationDate) THEN]%%

 %%=v(@RegistrationDate)=%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Is see in tags you search to do this in ampscript, i suggest you to put this information in title or in body !

Comment: arnaud it's not about the place. It is in the body.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You need to call ENDIF inside the ampscript block and needs to set some value after THEN condition.
Try like this

%%[
IF NOT EMPTY(@RegistrationDate) THEN
set @RegistrationDate=AttributeValue("RegistrationDate")
else
set @RegistrationDate_new=AttributeValue("RegistrationDate")
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@RegistrationDate_new)=%%

This code will display the RegistrationDate wherever present and will show blank if not available.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to show any date if the field is empty.

Comment: @Natalia - did this really solve your issue?

Comment: @Dalesha I changed it a bit but in general it works as it should so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You write, that you see the default date in the Ampscript code. Ampscript would never show a default date, if the data extension field and/or the variable is indeed empty. You don't write where or how you populate `@RegistrationDate`, so it is difficult for me to advice on how to solve this, but I suspect the data extension field is set to use a default value if a records is created without the date being set.

Additionally, there is a more efficient notation in Ampscript to do what you want to achieve - using [IIF](https://ampscript.guide/iif/) function:

```
%%=IIF(EMPTY(@RegistrationDate),'',@RegistrationDate)=%%
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but this solution wasn't working for me. I didn't have default value in Data Extension for this field so actually I don't know why it was displaying in email when the value in DE was empty. Nevertheless solution with AttributeValue helped.